# Getting Exception while running Stats-Aggregation in Elasticsearch 1.6

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 index types  a) Custom_Pattern_1, b) Custom_DataType_2 inside 'bw-2016-01-15-06-006' index.
For both of these index types, I have two field of same name but different data types

> 1. Custom_Pattern_1- Custom_DataType - String
> 2. Custom_DataType_2  - Custom_DataType - Long

I am running below query for aggregation.

```
POST bw-2016-01-15-06-006/Custom_DataType_2/_search
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 100,
  "aggregations" : {
        "Custom_DataType" : {
          "extended_stats" : {
            "field" : "Custom_DataType"
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Though I am running query only on Custom_DataType2 inside 'bw-2016-01-15-06-006' index in which Custom_DataType is long, it should have returned the results. But I am getting below ClassCastException.

```
{
   "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[-lo5bj-4TLOcyZwfl6oPyA][bw-2016-01-15-06-006][0]: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]}{[-lo5bj-4TLOcyZwfl6oPyA][bw-2016-01-15-06-006][1]: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]}{[-lo5bj-4TLOcyZwfl6oPyA][bw-2016-01-15-06-006][2]: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]}{[-lo5bj-4TLOcyZwfl6oPyA][bw-2016-01-15-06-006][3]: ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.plain.PagedBytesIndexFieldData cannot be cast to org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.IndexNumericFieldData]}]",
   "status": 500
}
```

I am still using **Elasticsearch 1.6** and according to documents one index can have 2 fields of same name with different data types.
Can somebody help me on this

Comment: This can happen if you've indexed a document whose `Custom_DataType` field was a long number inside a string (i.e. a numeric value surrounded with double quotes, like `"12345"`). The long value `12345` could have been inferred from the string at indexing time and indexed as a long, but the field data might still be considered a string. Can you verify that you're never indexing strings inside that field? If possible, wipe your index and properly re-index your data.

Comment: I have already confirmed the mapping. For one Type it is String and for another it is Long. And I have also put the data correctly.

Comment: If you want to be 100% certain that you're mapping doesn't accept numbers disguised as strings, you need to specify `coerce: false` and `ignore_malformed: true`. That's the only way, otherwise ES will accept `"12345"` (string) even for a field of type `long` as long as it can coerce a value that will fit into your field.

Answer (score 0):

It took some digging but I finally found the [article](https://orchestrate.io/blog/2014/09/30/improved-elasticsearch-indexing/) I was looking for. I remembered reading this some time ago. You can't have a field named exactly the same, in a different index, with a different data type because of the way Lucene stores the documents. This was actually an issue back in 0.9.2 but I can completely imagine it's made it's way through all the way to the 1.x releases, might be something worth checking out.